# What does ( integer ) mean in this Mysql query?

Tags: mysql, integer

Thanks everyone. Based on your responses, it looks like I'll be sending this one back. I thought it might be something I could fix quickly.

One of our clients sent us a script and one of the files had the following in it.

```
AND catparentid = '".( integer )."'";
```

Does anyone have any idea why the word "integer" would be inbetween the brackets or what it's supposed to be doing? I can't find anything about it online. It's the ending part of a sql query. The script is complaining about the "." in this query but I suspect the problem is the "integer" part...?

This is the full query....

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [|PREFIX|]categories WHERE catname = '".$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->quote( $prod )."' AND catparentid = '".( integer )."'";
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not valid SQL. It's most likely a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PHP error and not a MySQL one.

I can only speculate what this script is really supposed to do, but it's possible they meant to [cast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) a variable to integer because the `catparentid` column is an integer type (which is a good idea), but the variable isn't actually there:

```php
$sql = "..AND catparentid = '".( integer ) $catparentid ."'";
//                                         ^ forgot something?
```

However, seeing `[|PREFIX|]`, it's more likely just a placeholder [as Michael suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9419578/398242).

Comment: Thanks Madmartigan, the prefix part is a part of the greater shopping cart so it's used throughout all the scripts but yeah, that catparentid thing is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the client is just indicating that the value `catparentid` is supposed to be an integer, and that when performing the query in PHP, an integer variable should be substituted for `( integer )`.

```
// An integer...
$catparentid = 12345;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [|PREFIX|]categories WHERE catname = '".$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->quote( $prod )."' AND catparentid = '".$catparentid."'";
```

Or, since quoting a numeric value in MySQL isn't necessary:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [|PREFIX|]categories WHERE catname = '".$GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->quote( $prod )."' AND catparentid = $catparentid";
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's a bit mysterious because we aren't building it for the client, it's supposed to be ready to go. Hmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

```
AND catparentid = '".( integer )."'";
```

smells very strongly of PHP, where the dot is used as a string concatenator. I suspect this was cupy-pasted from PHP code and not fully sanitized.

In PHP this would create a string of sorts

```
AND catparentid = '( integer )'
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen. They used ".( somethinginthemiddle )." on all of their queries. New to me.